# How to call a base class method from a derived class instance?

Tags: c++, casting, virtual-functions

In the following code, how do I call the method `AbsBase::trycallmebase()` from an instance of class `Derived`? (call from outside of the two classes)

```
#include <iostream>

// Abstract base class
class AbsBase {
public:
   virtual void implement_me()=0;
   virtual void trycallmebase() { std::cout << "AbsBase::trycallmebase() \n"; }
};

// Concrete class
class Derived : public AbsBase {
public:
   virtual void implement_me() { std::cout << "Derived::implement_me() \n"; }
   virtual void trycallmebase() { std::cout << "Derived::trycallmebase() \n"; }
};

int main() {
    Derived derived;
    AbsBase* absbase = &derived;
    
    // try 1 : OK
    derived.trycallmebase();

    // try 2 : OK (virtual call in action)
    absbase->trycallmebase();
    
    // try 3 : Expected to print "AbsBase::trycallmebase()"
    static_cast<AbsBase*>(&derived)->trycallmebase();
}
```

Comment: `derived.AbsBase::trycallmebase()`

Comment: Wow! it works! what a strange syntax, I haven't seen before ... it's like a mixture of a static call (ClassName :: method ()) and as if AbsBase (a class name) were a data member of Derived class... What is this type of call called?